# Catch KeyboardInterrupt to raise KeyboardInterrupt

Tags: python, exception

I have some piece of code that looks like this:

```py
try:
    my_number = calculate_number()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    raise KeyboardInterrupt()
except:
    my_number = float('NaN')
```

My intention is that I try to calculate the number, if for whatever reason this cannot be done, just store a `NaN` value, unless the reason is obviously that the user does not want to calculate the number (e.g. by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>). Though this works as I want, I wonder if this is the correct way of implementing this, may it fail under some circumstance or if there is a more correct way of doing this.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to deal with `KeyboardInterrupt` explicitly. By catching `Exception` you exclude `KeyboardInterrupt` and a bunch of other "internal" exceptions you probably don't want to catch, but catch all other runtime errors.

```
try:
    my_number = calculate_number()
except Exception:
    my_number = float('NaN')
```

If you do want to handle everything but that specific exception, then I'd just re-raise using bare `raise` rather than raising a new `KeyboardInterrupt` exception. Raising a new one loses the information about where the exception originally occurred. This probably isn't very important for `KeyboardInterrupt` but is definitely important for other exceptions. An added benefit is that if you want to exclude multiple exceptions, you can lump them all into a single `except` clause because the code is the same for all of them.

```
try:
    my_number = calculate_number()
except KeyboardInterrupt, ZeroDivisionError:
    raise
except:
    my_number = float('NaN')
```

Combining the two approaches lets you not have to spell out which "system" exceptions not to handle, while also specifying "runtime" exceptions to be ignored.

```
try:
    my_number = calculate_number()
except ZeroDivisionError, OverflowError:
    raise
except Exception:
    my_number = float('NaN')
```

Comment: Interesting. I would appreciate if you can point me to the documentation of this specific behavior.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#KeyboardInterrupt -- it's because `KeyboardInterrupt` doesn't inherit from `Exception`.  If you did `except BaseException:` or the dreaded bare `except:` it'd catch `KeyboardInterrupt`.